# Spring dependency injection cycle

Tags: java, spring

I am running into dependency injection cycle problem. I am requesting redesign suggestions. Advance thanks.

**Error** Description: The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

Here are the two classes

Class 1:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

  private final Product1 finalProduct1;
  private final Product2 finalProduct2;

  @Autowired
  public MyService (Product1 product1, Product2 product2) {
     this.finalProduct1= product1;
     this.finalProduct2= product2;
  }

  public List<String> getMyValues(String someParameter) {
     ...
     return myValues;
  }
  ...
}
```

Class 2:

```
@Service
public class Product1 {

  @Autowired
  private MyService myService;

  public List<someType> someMethod(String someParameter){
      List<String> myValues = myService.getMyValues(someParameter);
      ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Please add your error log

Comment: You answered your question by asking it - there is dependency cycle, think about another architecture

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't ask a question. I am asking for redesign suggestions.

Comment: Ask yourself the question why the Product1 needs a service. Maybe you would add a method in the MyService class that receives the Product1 and does the magic with it.

Comment: `Product` does not sound like a service or another component, rather like an entity.  So maybe the problem is that you're trying to let Spring manage your entities which is not the point of Spring. Alternatives: Provide `MyService` as a method argument, put everything in a single service if it's related or extract the common functionality in a third component.

Comment: Thanks smsnheck and aha for your help. This will do. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a Dependency-Cycle as you answerd already in your question.

**What is the problem here?**

1. Spring tries to create a bean from `MyService`. Therefor it must call the constructor `MyService(Product1 product1, Product2 product2)`.
2. spring needs the dependency `Product1` and searches in the application context. It finds the class `Product1` which is annotated with the `@Service` annotation and tries to create a bean from it (calling the default constructor). Then it tries to inject the properties. Therefor it needs the `MyService`.. et voila. Cycle Dependency. Goto 1. and start over.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your annotating what seems to be a POJO or a Business Object with the @Service annotation, when that thing should most certainly not be a service.